# Content-position dependents of image size

Tags: html, css, image, screen-size

I have a problem with a part of my website. In my navigation bar the backgrounds image resizes with the display size. This means that if the display size gets bigger the image gets bigger and if the display size gets smaller the image gets smaller.
Now I have a content on is site whose position schould be dependent from the size of the image. That means if starts on the halfe(50%) of the display on display size it has e.g. to start at 60% of the display on an other display size. So you see the position is dependent on the size of the image.
Here is my code to make the size of the image dependent of the display size:

```html
    <style type="text/css">


    html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    #hintergrund {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; }

    #content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: auto;
    }

    </style>

    <body>
    <img id="hintergrund" src="http://www.frank-liedermacher.de/bilder/navi.jpg" border="0" alt="Hintergrundbild">
      </body>
```

How could I realize what I want to have. Is it posible to do this only with html and css?

Thank you
Crane

Comment: I can't see any background image.

Answer (score 0):

All background property here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

```
#hintergrund {
    background-image: url('http://www.frank-liedermacher.de/bilder/navi.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I didn't wanted such an answer. I don't have a problem with the background or a image that looks like a background. I want to use exactly my solution for the "background".
What I want to know is how I can position a part of may content dependently of the size of the image. With my posted methode the image changes the size with the display size. So at a higher display size the image gets bigger. That means the hills you can see are at higher display size lower at the screen than at a lower display size. And what I want to do is that a part of my content starts at every display size at the position of the hills in the image.